# What am I doing in this terminal?: C Programming

Tags: c, ubuntu

here is the source code of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_authentication(char *password)
{
if(strcmp(password, "brillig") == 0)
 return 1;

if(strcmp(password, "outgrabe") == 0)
 return 1;

   return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
if(argc < 2)
{
 printf("Usage: %s <password>\n", argv[0]);
 exit(0);
   }

   if(check_authentication(argv[1]))
   {
  printf("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
  printf(" Access Granted.\n");
  printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
    }
      else
     {
   printf("\nAccess Denied.\n");
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

What Am I exactly doing to the program in this image?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSQCg.png.

When I try to run this program in windows I can't input anything into it, but in UBUNTU I think I'm inputting something, but I'm not really sure what's going on.

This is what happens if I run it in windows https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt7gw.png,

By the way the whole point of the program was to demonstrate a buffer overflow.

---

Linux invocations, taken from screenshot:

```
 $ ./auth_overflow AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Access Denied.

 $ ./auth_overflow AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
  Access Granted.
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
```

Comment: Huh?  What do you mean "what am I doing to the program"?  Why can't you trace the program's execution with a debugger, or by adding print statements?

Comment: I am as confused as you are my friend...

Comment: You're... giving parameters on the command line?

Comment: I think OP means _why, when I invoke it with some specific arguments, do I apperently get the wrong behaviour ?_ ... although since the parameters aren't that long, text would have worked better than a screenshot of a terminal

Comment: I think that in Windows you're just doubleclicking the exe and not giving it any parameters.  argv[1] is the first parameter on the command line (argv[0] is the program name), you're inputting nothing at all, at least not in the sense of stuffing things in the program's stdin.  As why it crashes, no idea, IMO it shouldn't do that.  On windows, try opening a cmd window, go to that dir, and type the commands you also use in Ubuntu.  That should give the same results.

Comment: @Fvu I think your on to something, so on the ubuntu I'm inserting something into the parameter? I just want to know what I'm doing to the program in the terminal. Am I executing the program then giving it values or?

Comment: What's with those red lines in the Windows screenshot?

Comment: char *argv[] is the list of command line parameters, so each string on the command line gets placed into that array.

Comment: This is similar to a program in a question posted yesterday or so -- except that *that* program had a buffer overflow problem. I see no such problem in this program. Are you *certain* that this program shows the behavior indicated by the screenshots?

Comment: Alright, I'm coming from a C++ background this is most likely why this is confusing me. I'm just asking is why can't I input anything when I type the program in codeblocks and hit run and build. I thought in order to input something into the program you needed to have a specific command in their, which is from a C++ background the cin statement.                                                             Let me give you an example through C++

Comment: In particular, the behavior you report on Windows is consistent with the *old* version of the program from the old (now deleted, I think) question.

Comment: @ Keith Thompson, their is no problem with the program, the Program was made to demonstrate the bufferoverflow, i'm just wondering what i'm doing to the program in the terminal.

Comment: @Loseb: `cin << ...` (which, note carefully, is C++, not C) reads input from the keyboard, or from a file if input has been redirected. Your program accesses `argv`, which is initialized from the command-line arguments. Two different ways of getting information into your program.

Comment: @Loseb: If there's no problem with the program, why are you posting here? There's certainly a problem somewhere. The most likely explanation of the symptoms you're seeing is that you're accidentally running the old version of the program. Are you sure you recompiled *on both systems* it after modifying the source? Check the timestamps of the `.c` and `.exe` files.

Comment: Ah, so argv can only take input from a command line argument, that's very interesting I have never heard of this in C++, so that's why the concept seems to foreign to me. I always thought C++ and C were the same but C had a bit of a different syntax, but now it seems to be  a even more complex difference. Thank you, you have answered my question.

Comment: @Loseb looks like you need to refresh some basics there, as command line handling in C++ is actually identical to the way C does it - see [here](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/2131-05/labs/Lab3/CommandLineArguments.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OP's comment:

> Alright, I'm coming from a C++ background this is most likely why this
>   is confusing me. I'm just asking is why can't I input anything when I
>   type the program in codeblocks and hit run and build.

You are reading your input from `argv`, which is the list of paramaters provided on the command-line when your program is run.  When you use the 'run' command built into your IDE, your program is run with no command-line arguments (by default, at least).  Instead of running the program through your IDE, open a command prompt and run the program manually.  That way, you can run the program with parameters (like you did in the Linux shell) so that there is something in `argv` for your program to read.

Comment: Yes, this was the answer to my question.